# Booting from USB stick with Ubuntu 20.04 not possible

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, bootloader, grub-efi

I have bought an Acer Aspire desktop with Windows 10.

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 and establish a dual boot on a external SSD with USB connection.

Then I made a USB stick bootable with Rufus with the Ubuntu ISO file.(I have done that so many times before on another desktop). In the BIOS setting boot options I could not choose "boot from USB". But I could choose "Removable Device" instead and put this on top.

I disabled secure boot and fast startup. Then I shut down the computer and started it up again. The menu with the "try" or "install" options did not show up. But the desktop started Windows 10 instead. I shut down the desktop again and made a start up with the function key <kbd>F12</kbd>.

There I found my Windows boot manager and the USB stick. I choose for the USB stick (with Ubuntu 20,04 ISO on it) and made my Ubuntu partitions on the external SSD. The Windows10 partitions were not present (visible). When I choose continue, the system asked to make an EFI partition which I did.

After the installation was completed, I started up the desktop again. The machine booted right into Ubuntu. There was no grub menu. When I started the desktop again with function key <kbd>F12</kbd>, I could choose between windows boot manager or Ubuntu. Ubuntu is the first boot option.

So, my questions are:

1. Why can I not boot from USB in the BIOS menu and
2. Why can I (and also Gparted)not see my Windows partitions?

Comment: Did you make a second EFI partition on your external hard drive?  You should only have one EFI there is probably already one on the disk with Windows.

Comment: I have solved the problem.I changed my Bios setting. I replaced Intel RST Premium by AHCI.

Comment: Please post the details of your solution as an answer below.

Comment: You could contribute to the common knowledge here, so that others may profit from it. Some day you may have a question that you can't answer..

Comment: I have SOLVED my problem.
 
1. I replace in Bios settings Peripherals,Sata Mode
 settings Intel Premium with AHCI.
 
2. efibootmgr -v <enter> shows the boot options (F12)
 efibootmgr -o <enter> means make  changes
 Output before changing:
 user@user:~$ efibootmgr <enter>
 BootCurrent:0000
 Timeout: 1 seconds
 BootOrder: 0000,0002
 Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
 Boot0002* ubuntu
 Then:
 sudo efibootmgr -o 0002 <enter>
 
 System now starts up with grubmenu with Ubuntu
 on top. Followed by Windows10.
 Now I am satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have SOLVED my problem.
```

1. I replaced in Bios settings Peripherals,Sata Mode
   settings Intel Premium with AHCI.
2. efibootmgr -v  shows the boot options

   efibootmgr -o  means make  changes

   Output before changing:

   user@user:~$ efibootmgr  (enter)

   BootCurrent:0000

   Timeout: 1 seconds

   BootOrder: 0000,0002

   Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager

   Boot0002* ubuntu

Then:
sudo efibootmgr -o 0002

```
System now starts up with grubmenu with Ubuntu
on top. Followed by Windows10.
Now I am satisfied.
```